# How to insert a row into a that table has an increment id with CachedRowSet?

Tags: java, javadb, cachedrowset

I'm trying to insert a row into a table that has an increment id with CachedRowSet(I'm using Java wit Java DB), but I got the following SQLException:
**java.sql.SQLException: Failed on insert row 

        at... 

SQLState: null

Error Code: 0

Message: Failed on insert row** 
Here's my code snippet:

```
private static String urlString = "jdbc:derby:testdb;create=true";
private static String userName = "testUser";
private static String password = "testPassword";
...

CachedRowSet crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
            crs.setUrl(urlString);
            crs.setUsername(userName);
            crs.setPassword(password);
            crs.setCommand("SELECT * FROM test_table");
            crs.execute();

            crs.moveToInsertRow();
            crs.updateString("str_value", "testValue");
            crs.insertRow();
            crs.moveToCurrentRow();
            crs.acceptChanges();
```

The SQLException is thrown from `crs.inertRow()`.
The CachedRowSet works well if the table does not have an auto increment id.
How can I successfully do this?

other details:
I use the following code to create my table:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(urlString, userName, password);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE test_table("
                    + "id INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),"
                    + "str_value VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,"
                    + "CONSTRAINT primary_key PRIMARY KEY (id))");
            System.out.println("Talbe test_table created.");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of [Failed on insert row using CachedRowSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596022/failed-on-insert-row-using-cachedrowset).

Unfortunately, that happens because of the [API definition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#insertRow%28%29):

> Throws:
>   SQLException - if a database access error occurs; the result set concurrency is CONCUR_READ_ONLY, this method is called on a closed result set, if this method is called when the cursor is not on the insert row, or ***if not all of non-nullable columns in the insert row have been given a non-null value***

You may be better off using `JdbcRowSetImpl`.
You can only stick with the `CachedRowSet` if you remove the `NOT NULL` constraint of the `id` column. Unfortunately, this would also mean to remove the PK constraint. I'd assume that is too big a sacrifice, but it's either that or no `CachedRowSet`.

Comment: I check that question already before post,seems it really doesn't have a 'perfect' solution.

Comment: Well, sometimes you can't have 'perfect'. ;) I had another idea, but I guess it's even less perfect. :(

Answer (score 1):

try this
`crs.updateNull(1);
 crs.insertRow();`

where 1 is your PK. Worcked for me in MySQL